# How to force particular protocol through particular connection?

Tags: 14.04, networking

I'm not good with networking and maybe I'm using a wrong wording but I cannot find an answer. I'm using Ubuntu Desktop and I'd like to receive my ssh traffic via one of my connections and all ther rest of my traffic via some other connection. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you mean, you have two NICs and you want to use one for only SSH traffic and the other one for all other traffic?

Comment: Your NICs will be listening on two different addresses. The SSH server can be made to listen on one of these addresses only. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Strictly speaking in my case one of the connections is wi-fi and one is ethernet.

Comment: But I expect if I had two NICs it would be more or less the same.

Comment: @Kalmar: Ethernet and Wifi are two different NICs.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [sshd_config](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5?query=sshd_config&sec=5) what formats of ListenAddress are supported.

You should specify the IP of your Ethernet card, I assume it is fixed (otherwise you'll have a lot of hoops to jump through).

To isolate traffic from the WiFi I would suggest to use a firewall (e.g. `ufw`) and disable incoming connections on port 22.